# go vet - loop variable i captured by func literal

Tags: loops, go, concurrency, goroutine

In the below code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
        go func() {
            fmt.Println(i)
        }()
    }
}
```

---

Output:

```
code$ 
code$ go install github.com/myhub/cs61a
code$ bin/cs61a 
code$
```

---

Above program does not provide any output.

1) Is their a data race for single memory location `i` among 10 go-routines?

2) Why above code does not print value of free variable `i`?

Comment: This is also covered in the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#closures_and_goroutines

Answer (score 10):

> Is there a data race?

Yes, confirm it by running `go run -race example.go`. The main goroutine writes `i`, and the other goroutines read it without any synchronization. See [Passing parameters to function closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30183669/passing-parameters-to-function-closure/30183888#30183888); [Why do these two for loop variations give me different behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44715882/why-do-these-two-for-loop-variations-give-me-different-behavior/44716068#44716068) and [Register multiple routes using range for loop slices/map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44044245/register-multiple-routes-using-range-for-loop-slices-map/44045012#44045012).

> Why above code does not print anything?

Because when the main goroutine ends, your program ends as well. It does not wait for other non-`main` goroutines to finish. See [No output from goroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28958192/no-output-from-goroutine/28958240#28958240)

### Fix

Make a copy of the loop variable, and use that in the closures, and use a `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for the launched goroutines to end:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
    i2 := i
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println(i2)
    }()
}
wg.Wait()
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/UOmy_60wI_6)):

```
9
0
2
1
6
5
3
7
8
4
```

An alternative is to pass `i` as a parameter to the launched function:

```
var wg sync.WaitGroup
for i := 0; i <= 9; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(i int) {
        defer wg.Done()
        fmt.Println(i)
    }(i)
}
wg.Wait()
```

Try this one on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/lHnlu1033-o).

Comment: How `Add` & `Done` access `wg` to increment & decrement in an atomic way? from each go-routine

Comment: @overexchange Check their sources. They use the `sync/atomic` package among other things.

Comment: What happens, if I say `runtime.Gosched()` in `main()` after the for-loop statement? instead of using `wg`

Comment: @overexchange Nothing. `runtime.Gosched()` is not a synchronization tool, it (may) just help the scheduler. Without proper synchronization, you have no guarantee about goroutine execution order.